# How can I set an alias for a specific ssh command?

Tags: ssh, alias

I'm a beginner in Linux, using Ubuntu.

I want to make it easier to login to a server using ssh.

In my institute, our login command is `ssh -Y -p 4022 user@example.com`.

How can I make an alias for this?

Answer (score 3):

Add this to your `~/.ssh/config` file (or create the file with this content):

```
Host cuplogin2
    User user
    Hostname cuplogin2.ibs.re.kr
    Port 4022
    ForwardX11Trusted yes
```

Now you can login using:

```
ssh cuplogin2
```

If you want, you can also shorten the name next to `Host` if you want, e.g. `Host cl2`. Then, you can login using `ssh cl2`.

Comment: Thanks for reply! Is it impossible to omit ssh?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. You can make an alias to `ssh` like `alias s=ssh`, so then it would be `s cl2`, but isn't `ssh` short enough?

Comment: @HyungJoeKwon `alias s='ssh cl2'` is possible.

Comment: Thanks!! It really helps me!

Answer (score 0):

**Quick answer** You can add aliases into `~/.bashrc`. This is the file used to initialize environments when you open a terminal. So you should add the following command into `~/.bashrc`

```
# ssh alias
alias sshmein='ssh -Y -p 4022 user@cuplogin2.ibs.re.kr'
```

Do not forget the dot "." before filenames. You need to open a new terminal/ssh for the changes to be applied.

**Moreover**, if you ever opened `~/.bashrc`, you might find the following thing at the end:

```
if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi
```

which means all things in `~/.bash_aliases` will be "included" into `~/.bashrc`. So I always put my customized commands under `~/.bash_aliases`. This is the neater way.

The `.bashrc` can do many other things, for example

```
# extra PATH
PATH="$PATH:$HOME/Android/Sdk/platform-tools"
# joke commands
alias please='sudo'
```

If you want to apply some alias system-wide, edit `/etc/profile`, which is the `.bashrc` for all users.